# Display search result on another page

Tags: php, forms, search, include

can you help me with displaying output from search form ?
My search form is in sidebar and i would like to display result on main content div.
Navigation is done by switch

this is form in sidebar

```
<form name="searchform" method="get" action="index.php?page=search">
   <input type="text" name="searchword" size="15" />
   <input type="submit" name="search" value="Click" class="formbutton" />                   
</form>
```

this is switch that should include output to the main content:

```
 switch($_GET['page']){
    case "search":
      include("includes/search.php");
      break;
 }
```

and this is included search.php which should display result:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search_value = $_GET['searchword'];
    $query = " SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE keywords LIKE '$search_value'";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
        $post_id = $row['id'];
        $post_title = $row['title'];
        echo "<p><a href='index.php?page=post&&post=$post_id'>$post_title</a></p></ br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You should look into mysqli and prepared statements, that code you posted is wiiiiide open to sql injection

Comment: So what's happening currently?

Comment: i have this system secured. this is just basic code.

Comment: and nothing is happening when i click search.

Comment: Heh, that code you posted is most definitely not secured, basic or not.

Comment: This is not full code i posted here.  Why should i post here 200 line code when i need help with this particular part...

Answer (score 0):

What about if you specify a different page entirely in the form action instead of index.php? What you did is tell the form to use the index.php and send the GET data to it. If that doesn't help then be more specific on what you want

Comment: I want to send the GET data to search.php and display output with that switch on main content(include to index.php)

Comment: that search.php file. I send there data, i process them and it should display result.

Comment: What does it display when you send the search query

Comment: Nothing. It redirects me to default case in switch.  I think that problam will be in action in form but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: first of there is no $_GET['search'] in the output of your form. What you did there is set the value of $_GET['page'] to string 'search'. So the if(isset($_GET['search']) criteria doesn't run. So it should be $_GET['page']

Comment: still nothing happens. it creates bad URL. i think it should be www.aaa.com/index.php?page=search/... and so on, but it display this :www.aaa.com/index.php?searchword=iTypedThis&search=Click

Comment: i figured it out. only problem was method. with POST it works like charm. but thanks anyway